# Rhythmbox starts playing last song on album

Tags: nautilus, rhythmbox, music

This feels like a silly question, but I have a habit of navigating to my music directory using Nautilus, navigating to an album folder and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd> to play, which launches Rhythmbox.

Its an old Windows habit but I prefer this method of navigation due to the state of my id tags. However, on media players in Windows, the media player would always start from the start. In Ubuntu, Rhythmbox adds all the songs to the library then starts to play the *last* one...

How can I get Rhythmbox to play the songs from the start with this method. Or will I have to install a more basic lightweight player (suggestions)

Comment: You can also try audacious. It's a lightweight media player that does the job... :)